# How can I use my polygon erc20 custom tokens on other chains?

Tags: erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp, erc-721, ethereumjs, polygon

I am planning to launch polygon erc20 coin. But I have come to learn recently that interchain smart contract interaction is not possible.

If I want to use my polygon coins as a payment on ethereum dapp how can I do that?

```
IERC20 coinToken = IERC20(0x2de52C26AED95e4E618ec91b7F1cfb651214a4d8);
```

The above option will not work, I understand that. But is there any on chain way to verify coin ownership and take coins on ethereum dapp?

I am very new to blockchain. Please help.

Comment: As you said it yourself, if you want to use your coin on Ethereum you have to deploy it on Ethereum.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to bridge it over.  Polygon has a bridge here:  https://wallet.polygon.technology/.

But just note that it's usually not done.  Bridging costs gas, is time consuming, and has other risks depending on the bridge you use.  Usually you want to pay for things / use apps on polygon anyway since the gas is cheaper In fact, the usual way to do it is to mint your token on Ethereum and then bridge stuff over to Polygon for usage there.

Comment: So if I bridge my ethereum token to polygon, will I be able to use the the token for polygon apps. @thefett

Comment: But I have recently heard about coinvise. They basically deploy there air drop contract on polygon but for eligibility testing they check for a particular nft on ethereum. And they do it on chain using something name sub-graph. If that works for my erc20 token, I will not have to bridge over even.

Comment: Yes sir.  They'll have a different address, but work the same as any token: https://cointelegraph.com/news/how-to-bridge-tokens-from-other-chains-to-the-polygon-network

Comment: And you could just airdrop on polygon...I'd definitely just mint on the chain you plan to use the token on the most.  But also keep in mind that if you want to go to other chains later, most chains have bridges to ethereum, not polygon

Comment: https://mapper.polygon.technology/ is this also a bridging site? or mapping and bridghing are two different thing? Thank you, @thefett

Comment: this just tells you what address the tokens are bridged to

Comment: hi again. I really need to take some decision based on our conversation. It would be helpful if we could connect on discord
Anyways, What I have understood so far- I deploy erc20 contract on ethereum, then try to bridge it over to polygon. That bridging service deploy a contract on my behalf and I get the address of the new contract. Then I can use that address as an interface in my polygon dapp's solidity file. Is this correct?
But can I deploy 2 contracts for my same coin one on ethereum and the other on polygon? Is it a good solution? Or in future it may create some inconsistency?@thefett